# Functions in global context

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I understand that functions called without the "new" keyword spit out all their properties on to the global context. But I am seeing some curious behavior, with this piece of Javascript code:

```
function Test3() {
  var a=0;

  this.inc = function() {
    return ++a;
  };

  this.noInc = function() {
    return a;
  };

  this.testRef = function() {
    return this;
  };

  return {
    inc: inc,
    testRef: testRef,
    noInc: noInc
  };
}

var o = Test3();      // Put func properties on global context
var o2 = Test3();     // Put func properties on global context (replacing properties above??)

// Both "o" and "o2" maintain their own copy of "a" (closure)

alert("o:  " + o.inc());        
alert("o:  " + o.inc());        
alert("o:  " + o.inc());        // Will output 3 (as expected)

alert(noInc());                   // Output: 1 (This seems to not be affected by o.inc() calls - expected)

// However...
alert("o2: " + o2.inc());
alert("o2: " + o2.inc());
alert("o2: " + o2.inc());       
alert("o2: " + o2.inc());       // Will output 4 (as expected)

alert(noInc());                 // Will output 4 (seems to share with o2), but why?


alert(o === window);             // false    
alert(o.testRef() === o);        // true     (I thought testRef() would be on global context?)
alert(o.testRef() === window);   // false    (^^)

alert(o2 === window);            // false
alert(o2.testRef() === o2);      // true     (I thought testRef() would be on global context?)
alert(o2.testRef() === window);  // false    (^^)

alert(testRef() === window);     // true     (How come this is here? Look at comments above)
```

1. When we call `var o = Test()`, what exactly happens here? What context does `Test()` execute in. Since the `new` keyword is missing, I believe, `this` inside `Test3()` would refer to window? What does "o" refer to? Is it simply a variable declared on the global context?
2. If above is true, then how are o and o2 able to maintain separate copies of Test3's local variable "a". I understand that we have closure in action here, but then how come, "o2" and "window" share the same copy of the variable "a", but NOT "o"
3. When I do var o = Test3() and then do alert(o.testRef() === window), it says false. So after executing:

   ```
   var o = Test3();
   var o2 = Test3();
   ```

There seems to be 3 copies of the properties from `Test3()`. One on "o", another one on "o2" and one on the global context.

But how can there be any on "o" and "o2" - I am not calling `Test3()` with the "new" keyword, so this should only refer to global context?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and add the line, `"use strict";` to the top of your script.

Comment: Working in JSBin. I think it has "strict" enabled by default. Tried putting use strict; but JSBin is complaining about that line. What will having "strict" do?

Comment: @TahaAhmad Did you put `"use strict";` or `use strict;`? You should be using the one with the quotes...

Comment: In "strict" mode, the value of `this` in a function called without a context is `undefined` instead of `window`, so those assignments will all fail.

Comment: I see... However, in this case, I would like to understand what is going on here, where "this" is implicitly defaulted to global context.

Comment: Or, with strict, I could do var o = Test3.call(window), and my questions still remain (the behavior does not change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `Test3`, the `inc`, `noInc` and `testRef` functions are reassigned to `window` with a different `a` (which is initialized to `0` at the top of the function.)

`window` and `o2` share the same `a` because the functions were reassigned to `window` when `o2` got the return value and not `o1`.

Example from NodeJS REPL (note in NodeJS, the global object is referenced by `global` instead of `window`, but otherwise there shouldn't be any difference):

```
> function Test3() {
...   var a=0;
... 
...   this.inc = function() {
...     return ++a;
...   };
... 
...   this.noInc = function() {
...     return a;
...   };
... 
...   this.testRef = function() {
...     return this;
...   };
... 
...   return {
...     inc: inc,
...     testRef: testRef,
...     noInc: noInc
...   };
... }
undefined
> var o = Test3();
undefined
> o.inc()
1
> o.inc()
2
> o.inc()
3
> noInc()
3
```

Because `Test3` was only called once and set to `o1`, both the global scope and `o1` share an `a`. Now watch as I call `Test3` again:

```
> Test3()
{ inc: [Function],
  testRef: [Function],
  noInc: [Function] }
> noInc()
0
> o.noInc()
3
```

The functions are reassigned to the global object, with an `a` of `0`, while `o` keeps the previous `a`.

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Comment: One follow up question:

In my code, before var o = Test3(), if I do var o4 = new Test3(), the code stops working and gives the error - "ReferenceError: inc is not defined". What is going on here?

Comment: @TahaAhmad: Since `this` doesn't refer to `window` anymore, `this.inc = function() {...}` does *not* create a global variable and `return { inc: inc, ...}` throws an error because `inc` is not defined in any scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
var inc, noinc, a = 0, a2 = 0;
inc = function () {
   a += 1;
}
noinc = function () {
   return a;
}
inc();
inc();
inc();
noinc(); // 3

inc = function () {
   a2 += 1;
}
noinc = function () {
   return a2;
}
// now inc and noinc are bound to a2
noinc(); // 0, yours gives 1?
```

So basically you're overriding the definition of `inc` and `noinc` bound to a different `a`.

If instead of `var a = 0` you had `this.a = this.a || 0` you would bind to the *same* `a`.

Comment: This is not what my code is doing:

o.inc(), o2.inc() maintain their own copies of "a". However o2 seems to share the "a" on the global context

Comment: That's not accurate. `o2` doesn't share `a` (it's _private_), it's just that `this.inc === o2.inc`. If you did `o3 = Test3()` now `o3` will be what `o2` was before, and `o2` will be like `o`.

Comment: Excellent. But then where did window.inc() come from or rather where did o.inc() come from? Isn't Test3() executing in the global context (window) and therefore inc() should only be available on window. And if yes, what causes "o" to get inc() (and the rest of the properties)?

Comment: @TahaAhmad In non-strict bare-function invocation (i.e., not a method or event listener or with `call`/bind`, etc.), `this` is set to `window`, so `window.inc` was set when you set `this.inc`. Since `window` is the global object, `inc` refers to `window.inc`, since you don't have an `inc` identifier in scope chain before the global `inc`.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I don't understand is where did o and o2 get inc() from?

Comment: @TahaAhmad `o` gets `inc` because you return an object from `Test3` that has `inc` as one of its property names (whose value is set to `window.inc`.) You're doing `return { inc: window.inc, ... }` and that returned object is stored into `o`. You could do `return { inc: "foobar" }` and `o` would still have an `inc` property (whose value is the string `foobar`).

Comment: @apsillers Thank you for this explanation. I was confusing a part of my own code. This clears it up!